# Get week end date using current date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to get week end date using current date in sql server 2008?

I want week end date using current date in sql server.Is there any way.Today 31-12-2013 and I want week end date is 1-04-2014

Comment: did you try searching first? My guess would be "no"

Comment: Shows about as much effort as one of your previous (closed) questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494962/get-today-date-using-php-just-like-javascript   (also about dates)

Comment: Is there any way? Yes there is.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, getdate())), getdate())
```

**OR**

```
SELECT DATEADD (D, -1 * DatePart (DW, GETDATE()) + 7, GETDATE())
```

And this query for Week end Date and Week Start Date

```
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [WeekStart],
        DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [WeekEnd]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
SELECT DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,7,GETDATE()),6) 'Last Day of Last Week'
```